# mysql join returns whole table rather than results

Tags: mysql

I have a user table and a sales table. The sales table has a column user_id which i wish to join to the id column of the user table. My expected result is to get all the rows in the sales table with a user_id that matches the id column in the user table, so i can display the information from the logged in user.

My query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM user u JOIN sales s ON ( u.id = s.user_id )
```

What happens though is i just get every row of the table as a result.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're not using the logged in user's id anywhere in the query, so the database will return the data for all users. Typically you want to add a `WHERE u.id = @mycurrentuserid` at the end, where `@mycurrentuserid` is the logged in user's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `WHERE` clause which filters out the current user's rows, something like

```
SELECT * FROM user u JOIN sales s ON ( u.id = s.user_id )
WHERE u.User = 'someone'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current SQL you are joining the tables but your use case is more like left outer join.
use this query

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN user u
ON u.user_id=s.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you are trying is making the cartesian product of the result. So it shows all the rows in table.

You should try `Inner Join`, `Left Outer Join` or `Right Outer Join` instead as per your need.

Comment: Cartesian how? `JOIN` without qualifiers is the same thing as `INNER JOIN`.